# Downloading images from Reddit using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, http, reddit

I have been working on this small project in order to fetch top-notch images from Reddit. Overall I am pretty confident about the code below but I am not entirely sure about whether my error handling conforms to best practices or not. (Obviously account-related data has been 'censored'.) Thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import praw # reddit API Wrapper
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import urllib.request as web
import shutil # shell utilities
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

def main(subreddit_name = 'all', current_dir = os.getcwd()):
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id = 'censored', 
        client_secret = 'censored', 
        username = 'censored', 
        password = 'censored', 
        user_agent = 'subreddit crawler')

    dir_path = os.path.join(current_dir,subreddit_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
        os.mkdir(dir_path)

    colorama.init(autoreset = True)
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name).top(limit=1000)

    print("Download files...")

    for submissions in subreddit:
        if not submissions.stickied and submissions.score > 50:
            fullfilename = os.path.join(dir_path, "{}.jpg".format(submissions))
            request = web.Request(submissions.url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})
            with web.urlopen(request) as response, open(fullfilename, 'wb') as out_file:                
                try:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
                except HTTPError as e:
                    print("{}{}{}".format(Fore.RED, e.code, Style.RESET_ALL))
                except URLError as e:
                    print("{}{}{}".format(Fore.RED, e.reason, Style.RESET_ALL))                 

            # delete corrupted files smaller than 55 KB
            filesize = os.path.getsize(fullfilename)
            if filesize < 55000:
                os.remove(fullfilename)
            else:
                # this is for debugging purposes only
                temp = "{}[{:07d}KB]{}".format(Fore.GREEN, filesize, Style.RESET_ALL)
                print("{} ID: {} URL: {}".format(temp, submissions, submissions.url))

    dir_count = len(os.listdir(dir_path))
    print("Download succeeded. {} files saved in '{}'.".format(dir_count, dir_path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('PrequelMemes')
```

Comment: What's the point of providing both an ID/secret and a username/password? Are you sure all the fields are required when building `praw.Reddit`?